# eclipse: autoindent for xml (particularly build.xml) files?

Tags: eclipse, auto-indent

I really like Eclipse's autoindent feature for .java files, but when I hit Ctrl-I with build.xml open, it just erases the selection.

Is there any way to get autoindent for .xml files working in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Developers and RCP/Plug-in Developers packages of Eclipse include an XML editor which supports auto indentation of XML files.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: So does the WTP (Web Tool Package).

Comment: and... er... how do I find out whether my eclipse version is one of the packages you mention? if not how do I modify this?

Comment: Problem solved... I had my build.xml file opened in the text editor, not the XML editor. In the XML editor (built into the standard Java version of Eclipse), it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In the xml perspective under Source there is a Format option (CTRL+Shift+F)